# How does New Shepard Crew Capsule sense proximity to trigger retropropulsion just before impact?

Tags: landing, new-shepard, propulsive-deceleration

How does the New Shepard Crew Capsule sense proximity to the ground in order to trigger retropropulsion just before impact?

GIFs from [Blue Origin NS-10: New Shepard launch & landing, 23 January 2019](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YUzYCDbDlnc)

For example, Soyuz uses a gamma ray altimeter for several reasons:

- [How does a gamma ray altimeter work? What kind of sensor is used?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/26904/12102)
- [Soyuz landing ground detection](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/26899/12102)

[image: Blue Origin NS-10: New Shepard launch & landing, 23 January 2019]

[image: Blue Origin NS-10: New Shepard launch & landing, 23 January 2019]

For reference:

[image: Soyuz MS-08 landing]

GIF from [Soyuz MS-08 landing](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GWusG5EW3dU)

Comment: Early Russian Voskhod capsules used a telescoping rod sensor. Contact with the ground triggered the landing rockets. Usually. But testing revealed reliability problems under challenging landing conditions. The early gamma ray altimeter used in Soyuz had a Cobalt-60 radioisotope gamma source https://rtc-ru.translate.goog/solution/kaktus/?_x_tr_sl=auto&_x_tr_tl=en&_x_tr_hl=en In 1975 the radiation source was switched to Cesium-137. https://books.google.ca/books?id=-owpil83NRMC&pg=PA82&lpg=PA82&dq=soyuz+kaktus&source=bl&ots=NKcJhC-Xwq&sig=5Wgn_DTAgSx15hUR81LAtYpOZNw&hl=en&sa=X&ei=t_PfUN2UDs70igKF

Comment: I could find no published information of the type of proximity fuse used by New Shepard, but there are significant safety issues with cesium-137. Cobalt-60 is more civilian friendly but the presence of a gama source would complicate emergency efforts in case of a landing accident. Fools rush in and all that. Proximity fuses have been used extensively in artillery shells since WWII. Radio frequency sensors are robust enough to be launched inside artillery shells. If I were a paying Blue Origin passenger, I would rather share a capsule with a radio than a gamma source. Recent news coverage menti

Comment: on a new landing system but the talking head didn't give away any secrets.

Comment: @Woody The problem is not in reliably detecting the ground, but in reliably not detecting not-ground.  Bad things would happen if your proximity sensor was triggered by vegetation.

Answer (score 4):

New Shepard had two separate sensors for ground proximity, for its flights on 2020 Oct 13 and 2021 Aug 16.

Section III of [New Shepard Flight Test Results from Blue Origin De-Orbit Descent and Landing Tipping Point](https://doi.org/10.2514/6.2022-1829), by Bieniawski et al, AIAA 2022-1829, reports:

> The final set of sensors included the **NDL [Navigation Doppler
> LiDAR]** from NASA Langley, the DLC [Descent and Landing Computer]
> from NASA JSC, and the **OMPS [Optical Moon Proximity Sensor]**
> procured from OADS [Optical Air Data Systems]. The NDL consists of an
> electronics box and laser connected by fiber optic cables to three
> telescopes mounted at fixed angles within one of the transition
> tunnels.
> The NDL sends near infrared (1550 nm wavelength) laser
> beams to the surface, and the reflected returns are detected to
> provide an estimate of the lander’s velocity and range relative to the
> ground.
> ...
> The OMPS ... consists
> of a small electronics box and four telescopes. The measurement
> principle, while still a LiDAR at 1550 nm wavelength, is different
> from the NDL and leverages OADS’s years of development in terrestrial
> LiDARs for wind turbines, helicopters, and aircraft.

The NDL LiDAR is documented [here](https://arc.aiaa.org/doi/10.2514/6.2013-5312).

The NDL was the one used for real-time navigation, while the OMPS's measurements were only recorded for post-flight evaluation.

*Correction:*  The NDL and OMPS were mounted near the top of the booster, rather than on the crew capsule, as shown in part of figure 4 in the paper (below), and as implied by figure 12 which is a photo of the booster just before landing annotated with laser directions.

[image: figure 4 of the paper]

Blue Origin's [fact sheet](http://www.parabolicarc.com/2020/02/23/blue-origin-new-shepard-fact-sheet/) says that

> Right before touching down, a retro thrust system expels a cloud of air beneath the capsule to create a gentle landing around 1 mph in the West Texas desert.

This retropropulsion (not a rocket, just a tank of compressed air?) must be commanded by software just like all aspects of its flight.  But I don't know what kind of sensor triggers that command.

Comment: *Moon* Proximity?

Comment: Yep.  This [report](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/api/citations/20210026314/downloads/Blue%20Origin%20De-Orbit%20Descent%20Landing%20Tipping%20Point%20Final%20Report.pdf) says it's intended for the Blue Moon Commercial Lunar Lander, and the New Shepard flights were testing it for that.  But I understand your confusion :)

Comment: Were these used on the crew capsule? It seems to only be for the booster